# Blocks in combination with bullets spacing

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, shapes

I have been trying to create my second Tikz model based on [TikZ: Diagram of a perceptron](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104334/tikz-diagram-of-a-perceptron). I have manage to modify it based on my beginners knowledge and experimentation but the part that I am missing and I can not figure out how to make the bullets. I am trying to make the distance smaller but there is not affect. I tried with `distance node = 1 em` but not successfully for the moment. Is there a possible solution to my problem? A sample of the output is provided.[image: Output] Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc} % braces {}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
 block/.style={
  draw, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=2em, 
  minimum width=5em,
 },
 sum/.style={
  draw, 
  circle, 
  minimum size=2em
 },
 input/.style={coordinate}, 
 output/.style={coordinate},
 mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text depth=4pt,
  text height=10pt
 }
}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']

% Blocks
\node[input, name = input] {};
\node[sum, right = of input, node distance = 1em] (sum) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum, node distance = 6.5em] (stream) {Stream $2$};
\node[sum, right = of stream, node distance = 1em] (filter) {$F_2$};
\node[sum, above = of sum, node distance = 5em] (sum_2) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_2, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_2) {Stream$1$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_2, node distance = 1em] (filter_2) {$F_1$};

% Bullets
\node[below of = sum, node distance = 3em] (dot) {$\bullet$} -- (dot);
\node[below of = dot, node distance = 1em] (dot_2) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_2);
\node[below of = dot_2, node distance = 1em] (dot_3) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_3);
\node[below of = stream, node distance = 3em] (dot_4) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_4);
\node[below of = dot_4, node distance = 1em] (dot_5) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_5);
\node[below of = dot_5, node distance = 1em] (dot_6) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_6);
\node[below of = filter, node distance = 3em] (dot_7) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_7);
\node[below of = dot_7, node distance = 1em] (dot_8) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_8);
\node[below of = dot_8, node distance = 1em] (dot_9) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_9);

% Blocks
\node[input, name = input_n] {};
\node[sum, below = of dot_3, node distance = 1em] (sum_n) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_n, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_n) {Stream $n$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_n, node distance = 1em] (filter_n) {$F_n$};

% Sum
\node[sum, right = of filter, node distance = 3em] (total) {$\sum$};

% Oneway delay
\node[block, right of = total, node distance = 7.5em] (delay) {One Way Delay};
\node[block, right of = delay, node distance = 15em] (segments) {$MP_1$ $|$ $Payload_1$ $\dots$ $MP_n$ $|$ $Payload_n$};
\node[output,right = of segments] (output) {};

% Inputs
\node[input,left = of sum_2] (output_2) {};
\node[input,left = of sum_n] (output_n) {};

% Lines Center Block
\draw[->] (input) -- node [name = begging] {$IN_2$} (sum);
\draw[->] (sum) -- node {} (stream);
\draw[->] (stream) -- node {} (filter);
\draw[->] (filter) -- node {} (total);
\draw[->] (total) -- node {} (delay);
\draw[->] (delay) -- node {} (segments);
\draw[->] (segments) -- node {Data} (output);

% Lines Above Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_2) -- node {} (stream_2);
\draw[->] (stream_2) -- node {} (filter_2);
\draw[->] (filter_2) -- node {} (total);

% Lines Below Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_n) -- node {} (stream_n);
\draw[->] (stream_n) -- node {} (filter_n);
\draw[->] (filter_n) -- node {} (total);

% Input Lines
\draw[->] (output_2) -- node {$IN_1$} (sum_2);
\draw[->] (output_n) -- node {$IN_n$} (sum_n);

\end{tikzpicture} }% End of makebox
\caption{New Tikz}
\label{fig:tikz }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd sugget you a different approach that will keep a consistent spacing between the layers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc} % braces {}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
 block/.style={
  draw, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=2em, 
  minimum width=5em,
 },
 sum/.style={
  draw, 
  circle, 
  minimum size=2em
 },
 input/.style={coordinate}, 
 output/.style={coordinate},
 mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text depth=4pt,
  text height=10pt
 }
}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']

% Blocks
\node[input, name = input] {};
\node[sum, right = of input, node distance = 1em] (sum) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum, node distance = 6.5em] (stream) {Stream $2$};
\node[sum, right = of stream, node distance = 1em] (filter) {$F_2$};
\node[sum, above = of sum, node distance = 5em] (sum_2) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_2, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_2) {Stream$1$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_2, node distance = 1em] (filter_2) {$F_1$};


% Blocks
\node[input, name = input_n] {};
\node[sum, below = of sum, node distance = 1em] (sum_n) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_n, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_n) {Stream $n$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_n, node distance = 1em] (filter_n) {$F_n$};

% Bullets
\foreach \Nodo in {sum,stream,filter}
{
  \node[rotate=90,font=\footnotesize] (dot) 
    at ( $ (\Nodo)!0.5!(\Nodo_n) $ ) {$\bullet\bullet\bullet$};
}

% Sum
\node[sum, right = of filter, node distance = 3em] (total) {$\sum$};

% Oneway delay
\node[block, right of = total, node distance = 7.5em] (delay) {One Way Delay};
\node[block, right of = delay, node distance = 15em] (segments) {$MP_1$ $|$ $Payload_1$ $\dots$ $MP_n$ $|$ $Payload_n$};
\node[output,right = of segments] (output) {};

% Inputs
\node[input,left = of sum_2] (output_2) {};
\node[input,left = of sum_n] (output_n) {};

% Lines Center Block
\draw[->] (input) -- node [name = begging] {$IN_2$} (sum);
\draw[->] (sum) -- node {} (stream);
\draw[->] (stream) -- node {} (filter);
\draw[->] (filter) -- node {} (total);
\draw[->] (total) -- node {} (delay);
\draw[->] (delay) -- node {} (segments);
\draw[->] (segments) -- node {Data} (output);

% Lines Above Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_2) -- node {} (stream_2);
\draw[->] (stream_2) -- node {} (filter_2);
\draw[->] (filter_2) -- node {} (total);

% Lines Below Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_n) -- node {} (stream_n);
\draw[->] (stream_n) -- node {} (filter_n);
\draw[->] (filter_n) -- node {} (total);

% Input Lines
\draw[->] (output_2) -- node {$IN_1$} (sum_2);
\draw[->] (output_n) -- node {$IN_n$} (sum_n);

\end{tikzpicture} }% End of makebox
\caption{New Tikz}
\label{fig:tikz }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The idea is to first draw all the blocks and then to use the `calc` library (which you already loaded) to place the bullets exactly halfway between the second and third layers (this can be done with a single loop):

```
% Bullets
\foreach \Nodo in {sum,stream,filter}
{
  \node[rotate=90,font=\footnotesize] (dot) 
    at ( $ (\Nodo)!0.5!(\Nodo_n) $ ) {$\bullet\bullet\bullet$};
}
```

Comment: I thought that there would be a solution to reduce the lines of rewriting something over and over. I am impressed by those small things, loops, new commands etc. Is there a source that I could read more about it, or is it based on experience? Thank you for your time and effort to assist me on my query.

Comment: @Thanos You're welcome. The official source (for PGF/TikZ) is the pgf manual (but it has become over the years a "little moster" of 1100+ pages). However, you can read the introductory examples and the specific parts that you need.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a size less than `1em`. Below I used `0.7em`:

[image]

### Notes:

- For vertical spacing one should use the `ex` dimension instead of `em` (which should be used for horizontal distance.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,calc} % braces {}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
 block/.style={
  draw, 
  rectangle, 
  minimum height=2em, 
  minimum width=5em,
 },
 sum/.style={
  draw, 
  circle, 
  minimum size=2em
 },
 input/.style={coordinate}, 
 output/.style={coordinate},
 mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text depth=4pt,
  text height=10pt
 }
}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex']

% Blocks
\node[input, name = input] {};
\node[sum, right = of input, node distance = 1em] (sum) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum, node distance = 6.5em] (stream) {Stream $2$};
\node[sum, right = of stream, node distance = 1em] (filter) {$F_2$};
\node[sum, above = of sum, node distance = 5em] (sum_2) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_2, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_2) {Stream$1$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_2, node distance = 1em] (filter_2) {$F_1$};

% Bullets
\node[below of = sum, node distance = 3em] (dot) {$\bullet$} -- (dot);
\node[below of = dot, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_2) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_2);
\node[below of = dot_2, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_3) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_3);
\node[below of = stream, node distance = 3em] (dot_4) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_4);
\node[below of = dot_4, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_5) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_5);
\node[below of = dot_5, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_6) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_6);
\node[below of = filter, node distance = 3em] (dot_7) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_7);
\node[below of = dot_7, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_8) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_8);
\node[below of = dot_8, node distance = 0.7em] (dot_9) {$\bullet$} -- (dot_9);

% Blocks
\node[input, name = input_n] {};
\node[sum, below = of dot_3, node distance = 1em] (sum_n) {MP};
\node[block, right of = sum_n, node distance = 6.5em] (stream_n) {Stream $n$};
\node[sum, right = of stream_n, node distance = 1em] (filter_n) {$F_n$};

% Sum
\node[sum, right = of filter, node distance = 3em] (total) {$\sum$};

% Oneway delay
\node[block, right of = total, node distance = 7.5em] (delay) {One Way Delay};
\node[block, right of = delay, node distance = 15em] (segments) {$MP_1$ $|$ $Payload_1$ $\dots$ $MP_n$ $|$ $Payload_n$};
\node[output,right = of segments] (output) {};

% Inputs
\node[input,left = of sum_2] (output_2) {};
\node[input,left = of sum_n] (output_n) {};

% Lines Center Block
\draw[->] (input) -- node [name = begging] {$IN_2$} (sum);
\draw[->] (sum) -- node {} (stream);
\draw[->] (stream) -- node {} (filter);
\draw[->] (filter) -- node {} (total);
\draw[->] (total) -- node {} (delay);
\draw[->] (delay) -- node {} (segments);
\draw[->] (segments) -- node {Data} (output);

% Lines Above Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_2) -- node {} (stream_2);
\draw[->] (stream_2) -- node {} (filter_2);
\draw[->] (filter_2) -- node {} (total);

% Lines Below Center Block
\draw[->] (sum_n) -- node {} (stream_n);
\draw[->] (stream_n) -- node {} (filter_n);
\draw[->] (filter_n) -- node {} (total);

% Input Lines
\draw[->] (output_2) -- node {$IN_1$} (sum_2);
\draw[->] (output_n) -- node {$IN_n$} (sum_n);

\end{tikzpicture} }% End of makebox
\caption{New Tikz}
\label{fig:tikz }
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So simple I did not even think about it. Thank you for your time and effort. I appreciate the assistance.